# Boolean is passed by reference but still i am getting compilation error in cpp

Tags: c++

I am writing code for finding cycle in undirected graph but there is an compilation error although i have already declared the array named "vis".

```
int dfs(vector<int> adj[], int v, bool[] &vis) {
    vis[v]=true;

    for(int x : adj[v]){
        if(vis[x]==true) return 1;
        vis[x] = true;
        dfs(adj, x, vis);
    }

    return 0; 
}

bool isCyclic(vector<int> adj[], int V) {
    // Your code here
    bool vis[V];

    cout << dfs(adj, V, vis);
}
```

Following errors i am getting:-

> ```
> prog.cpp:11:40: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
>  int dfs(vector<int>adj[],int v ,bool[] &vis){
>
>
>
> prog.cpp: In function 'int dfs(std::vector<int>*, int, bool*)':
>
>
> prog.cpp:12:5: error: 'vis' was not declared in this scope
>      vis[v]=true;
> ```

Comment: For some reason you declare the arrays of vectors correctly in the argument lists, but not the array of `bool`.

Comment: dfs(vectoradj[],int v ,bool[] &vis) to dfs(vectoradj[],int v ,bool& vis[])

Comment: Also note that even if you use the `[]` syntax for arguments, the compiler translates it as pointers. So `bool &vis[]` is really `bool*& vis`. That is, you pass a pointer by reference, which doesn't really make sense in the context of your code. Just pass a pointer `bool* vis`. Or start using `std::vector`, which you really should do anyway since C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: Should be `int dfs(vector<int> adj[], int v, bool vis[])` Note that ampersand is obsolate since in C this will be passed by pointer to array.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have an array of `v` elements, then `vis[v]` (and of course `adj[v]`) will be out of bounds.

Comment: Try `bool*&vis` instead of `bool[] &vis`

Answer (score 0):

Passing `bool[]` to the function is enough. `bool[]` is actually `bool*`, through which you can modify the elements in the array.

Comment: Be aware that `bool[] a` is not a valid sytax. The brakets must be after the name: `bool a[]`

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple problems here. I think there is a confusion about how array works and what is the syntax for them.

By default, raw arrays are passed around by reference. Arrays are not copied when passed around unlike normal variables.

In fact, a function recieving a pointer or a array is equivalent:

```
void frob(bool a[]); // both equivalent.
void frob(bool* a); // same function.
```

So changing you function to this signature should simply work:

```
int dfs(vector<int> adj[], int v, bool vis[]) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Also, runtime sized array is not a standard feature. You should use a vector instead.

```
// V is not constexpr, you should use vector
bool vis[V];
```

Here's how you would construct and pass the vector around:

```
int dfs(vector<int> adj[], std::vector<bool>& vis) {
    int v = vis.size();
    // ...
}

bool isCyclic(vector<int> adj[], int V) {
    // Your code here
    std::vector<bool> vis(V);

    cout << dfs(adj, vis);
}
```

Comment: Another option, for the sake of completeness, could be `bool (&vis)[N]` if `N` is a compile time constant. It does not apply to OP's specific problem but it can be helpful for others.

Comment: @JorgeBellon op used variable sized array, there is no mean to pass the array by reference.

Comment: I think that is not quite correct. You know of course about array decay to pointer. If you want, then you can pass an array by pointer or by reference. But of course only an array that has a compile time dimension. Like in ````int a[10];void func1(int (&a)[10]){} /* By reference */ void func2(int (*a)[10]){} /* by pointer */ func1(a);func2(&a);```` But of course the rule is: Do not use plain arrays in C++. No need.

Comment: @ArminMontigny of course. But again, OP used runtime size array (GCC extension) and those cannot be passed by reference at all. OP needed a vector instead. The best would be to use a `std::array` when dealing with a compile time sized array and `std::vector` otherwise. I fear OP also store it's vector into a runtime sized array.

Comment: @ Guillaume Racicot: Same understanding: Thanks for additional clarification. I agree again. Do not use VLA and do not use arrays in C++ at all.

Comment: The thing is `int (&a)[10]` is useful in some situations (it only works for non-VLA C-style arrays of exactly 10 elements). I explicitly noted that it does not apply for OP's particular problem but it might apply for someone looking to solve a similar problem. Example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array